# difference between git --assume-unchanged, git rm -r --cached and --skip-worktree

Tags: git, gitignore

Well, question is quite clear. In which scenario should I use  **git --assume-unchanged** or in what situation **git rm -r --cached** should be used?

Also, **--skip-worktree** is increasing the confusion.

Which is better to use with **.gitignore**?

Goal is to keep config files from getting pushed to github repo because there are often different settings on different deployment machines. Therefore, each machine would have their own config files.

Answer (score 2):

**assume-unchanged**

- It assumes that a developer shouldn’t change a file. This flag is
  meant for improving performance for not-changing folders like SDKs.
- It is just for local performance issues. If Git can determine that
     those files changed in a lighter way, it will.
- Local setting: The "assume-unchanged" bit is stored in your index,
     not in the repository itself. Thus fetch/pull/push do not propagate
     that setting to or from other repositories
- Assume-unchanged should not be abused for an ignore mechanism. It is
  not a promise by Git that Git will always consider these paths are
  unmodified

**rm -r --cached**

- Remove files from the working tree and from the index
- git rm --cached remove the file from the repo and not delete it from
  the local file system(git rm will remove the file from local file
  system)

**skip-worktree**

- skip-worktree is useful when you instruct git not to touch a specific
  file ever because developers should change it. For example, if the
  main repository upstream hosts some production-ready configuration
  files and you don’t want to accidentally commit changes to those
  files, --skip-worktree is exactly what you want. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/524700) post
  in SO

**Which is better to use with .gitignore?**

It depeneds. If you already added the config files in your git, then it is better to use

> git rm -r --cached

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/524700) post.